# How can i center my text in the box (background-color)

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.memes {
    top: 15px;
    left: 40px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    width: 330px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    animation-name: fel;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Kitti's wonders</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
    <div class="memes">
        <ul>
            <li><a style="text-decoration:none;color:white" href="memek.index">Kitti's stolen memes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="interruption">
    <a href="beszolasok.index" style="text-decoration:none;color:white" >Kitti's speeches</a>
    </div>
</html>
```

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m0uo.png

I wanna make it centered in the box and i want it equaily! Can anybody help?

Thanks
MDJArtz

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Can you be more specific in the way you format your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the problem is? Do you want the space to the left of the text gone?

If so add this to your css:

`ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}`

Comment: Thanks bro! You are awesome, but now this is my problem i wanna make it centered in the box https://i.imgur.com/SWR8NKZ.png I'm very new to this

Comment: @SulánLászló just add `text-align:center;` after `padding: 0;` in the small css @conordarcy already gave you